# D3.js nodes set bgcolor from array but never adjacent

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I have created a circle of nodes and label them 1-18 each with a unique ID so I can later manipulate the fill color.

Then from the array of colors, assign them to nodes but never have a color next to each other, with at least one grey node between them.

There is a total of 18 nodes and the array of colors has 8 that need to distributed across the nodes with the spacing rule.

I am stumped on getting all the colors assigned and having the spacing rule. I can get one or the other but not both.

Is there a simpler way to do the math and branch based on the last color?

```js
  //Many thanks to this champ for the inspiration http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe
    //Find the original code and demo here http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/3404776

      (function() {
        var colors = [
        'blue'
        ,'blue'
        ,'red'
        ,'red'
        ,'green'
        ,'green'
        ,'white'
        ,'white'
        ];
      var my_color = null;
      var lastchoice = [];

        function getColor(id) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (18));
            if (lastchoice.length === 0) {
              if (random < 8) {
                var my_color = colors.splice(0,1);
              } else {
                var my_color = 'grey';
              }
              lastchoice.push(random);
              return my_color;
           } else {
             for (i = 0; (i < lastchoice.length); i++) {
                    if (lastchoice.indexOf(random) < 0) {
                      break;
                  } else {
                  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (18));
                  continue;
                  }
              }
              if (random < 8) {
                var my_color = colors.splice(0,1);
              } else {
                var my_color = 'grey';
              }
              lastchoice.push(random);
              return my_color;

           }
           console.log(lastchoice);
      }

       var createNodes = function (numNodes, radius) {
         var nodes = [],
             width = (radius * 2) + 150,
             height = (radius * 2) + 150,
             angle,
             x,
             y,
             i;
         for (i=0; i<numNodes; i++) {
          angle = (i / (numNodes/2)) * Math.PI; // Calculate the angle at which the element will be placed.
                                                // For a semicircle, we would use (i / numNodes) * Math.PI.
          x = (radius * Math.cos(angle)) + (width/2); // Calculate the x position of the element.
          y = (radius * Math.sin(angle)) + (width/2); // Calculate the y position of the element.
          nodes.push({'id': i, 'x': x, 'y': y});
         }
         return nodes;
       }

       var createSvg = function (radius, callback) {
         d3.selectAll('svg').remove();
         var svg = d3.select('#canvas').append('svg:svg')
                    .attr('width', (radius * 2) + 150)
                    .attr('height', (radius * 2) + 150);
         callback(svg);
       }

       var createElements = function (svg, nodes, elementRadius) {
         g = svg.selectAll('g')
                        .data(nodes)
                      .enter().append('g')
                      .attr('id', function (d, i) {
                        return i;
                      })
         element = g.append('svg:circle')
                        .attr('r', elementRadius)
                        .style("fill", function(d, i){ return getColor(i); })
                        .style("stroke", "black")
                       .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
                          return d.x;
                        })
                        .attr('cy', function (d, i) {
                          return d.y;
                        });
          text = g.append("svg:text")
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
                .attr('x', function (d, i) {
                   return d.x;
                 })
                 .attr('y', function (d, i) {
                   return d.y+5;
                 })
                .text(function (d, i) {
                  return i+1;
                })
                .style({"font-weight":"bold", "font-size":"20px"});

       }


       var draw = function () {
         var numNodes = 18;
         var radius = 220;
         var nodes = createNodes(numNodes, radius);
         createSvg(radius, function (svg) {
           createElements(svg, nodes, 35);
         });
       }

      $(document).ready(function() {
          draw();
      });

      $("#radius, #numNodes").bind('keyup', function(e) {
          draw();
          lastchoice = [];
      });
            })();
```

```css
* {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      circle {
        fill: grey;
        fill-opacity: 1;
      }
      text{
          pointer-events:none;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

If you need another playground its here too:
http://jsfiddle.net/bigtoerag/4w5rk86z/

Comment: I managed to hack together a way to do it by writing the shuffled array to a hidden input then grab each element color when the D3 drawing of the circle happens.  The updated code is in   http://jsfiddle.net/bigtoerag/4w5rk86z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to hack together a way to do it by writing the shuffled array to a hidden input then grab each element color when the D3 drawing of the circle happens. The updated code is in jsfiddle.net/bigtoerag/4w5rk86z